# Make one controller dependent on scope of another controler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers: OperationController and DateController. In OperationController I have $scope, that contains "operations" array. I can change this operations from my app (remove, update, add...).

And I have second controller, that calculate days and days' values. This DateController need to take data from OperationController, and then it will calculate days-data. It need to calculate it on every update of operations.

How to bind these two controller thus DateController can get data from OperationController on first start and on every data update?

Comment: Use a service to store `operations` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a factory/service to store the `operations` array, whenever the value changes in the `OperationController` controller update the values

```
myApp.factory('myService', [function() {
        var operations = {};
        return {
            getOperations: function() {
                return operations
            },

            setOperations: function(op) {
                operations = op;
            },
        }
    }])
    .controller('OperationController', [function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.operations = {};
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $scope.operations;
        }, function() {
            myService.setOperations($scope.operations);
        });
    }])
    .controller('DateController', [function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.operations = myService.getOperations();
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this, but the recommended way to go is probably by using a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to store the `operations` related logic and declaring a dependency on that service in both controllers.